# Will the unified API have delegate auth for administrators?

Tags: office365, office365-apps

All other major storage providers provide administrator-level access via their APIS to individual user files. Will this be coming with the preview? Is this available now automatically, without having to grant specific permissions outside of the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this functionality is in the roadmap for unified API. It's not available now, but we will add it soon.